# Qt Dynamic Properties - Works for widget if not parented only?

Tags: python, qt, maya, pyside2

I'm trying to achieve a button behavior on a normal QWidget and I'm trying to use `setProperty()` to dynamically change values in the stylesheet.
It seems to works well when I show the widget using its `show()` method but once it is parented It does not works anymore, I don't understand what happen ?? (No, I don't want to inherit from QPushButton, the widget will be a lot different, thanks.)

There is an example:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Example(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    
    STYLESHEET = \
    """
    QWidget[pressed=true] 
    {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    QWidget[pressed=false] 
    {
        background-color: red;
    }
    """
    
    pressed = QtCore.Signal()
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        
        self._buildUi()

        self.setStyleSheet(self.STYLESHEET)

        self.setProperty('pressed', False)
        
    def _buildUi(self):
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('toto')
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.pressed.emit()
        self.setProperty('pressed', True)
        self.setStyle(self.style())
                
        super(Example, self).mousePressEvent(e)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.setProperty('pressed', False)
        self.setStyle(self.style())
        
        super(Example, self).mouseReleaseEvent(e)
        
        
class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
                
        self.test = Example(self)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.test)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # w = Example()  # Work
    w = Window()  # Don't Work
    w.show()
```

If you switch the commented lines in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` condition you will be able to see both result of the same widget.

I tried to:

- call widget mousePressEvent and mouseReleaseEvent from parent (just to test) - Don't work
- Send a StyleChange event manually to the QApplication - Don't work
- unpolish/polish manually - Don't work
- set the stylesheet again - Dont' work
- Inherit from QPushButton - Work, but not what I want (I need to understand how to make this work, not use the allready existing properties.)

PS:
I run this code inside Autodesk Maya, so the QApplication instance allready exists as it is Maya itself.

Do you guys know what happen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standalone widget works because Qt uses the basic stylesheet properties (background and border) *only for top level windows*, assuming that the top level window is of the same class as that specified in the stylesheet.

When a QWidget has a parent, it does *not* paint anything on its own.
As the [documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#qwidget-widget):

> If you subclass from QWidget, you need to provide a paintEvent for your custom QWidget

So, in PyQt/PySide terms:

```
class Example(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    # ...
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOption()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        self.style().drawPrimitive(
            QtWidgets.QStyle.PE_Widget, opt, qp, self)
```